# Java MicroStream Serialization, Type not persistable: "class java.lang.Throwable"

Tags: java, exception, serialization, microstream

When serializing an object containing a field of type Throwable I get

```
one.microstream.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionTypeNotPersistable: Type not persistable: "class java.lang.Throwable".
```

Using the Serializer or TypedSerializer like this:

```
class ObjectToSerialize {
    Throwable throwable;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize = new ObjectToSerialize();

        final SerializerFoundation<?> foundation = SerializerFoundation.New()
                .registerEntityTypes(ObjectToSerialize.class);
        final Serializer<byte[]> serializer = TypedSerializer.Bytes(foundation);
        byte[] data = serializer.serialize(objectToSerialize);

        ObjectToSerialize restored = serializer.deserialize(data);

    }
}
```

The result I get is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" one.microstream.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionTypeNotPersistable: Type not persistable: "class java.lang.Throwable".
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.BinaryHandlerUnpersistable.guaranteeSubTypeInstanceViablity(BinaryHandlerUnpersistable.java:98)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.lambda$recursiveEnsureTypeHandlers$0(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:278)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.internal.AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.iterateMemberTypes(AbstractBinaryHandlerReflective.java:591)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.recursiveEnsureTypeHandlers(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:271)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.registerTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:639)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.internalEnsureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:616)
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.ensureTypeHandler(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:384)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.util.SerializerFoundation$Default.createPersistenceManager(SerializerFoundation.java:211)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.util.TypedSerializer$Default.initialize(TypedSerializer.java:372)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.util.TypedSerializer$Default.<init>(TypedSerializer.java:262)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.util.TypedSerializer.New(TypedSerializer.java:145)
    at one.microstream.persistence.binary.util.TypedSerializer.Bytes(TypedSerializer.java:117)
    at com.testing.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253772/java-microstream-immutablepair-causing-persistenceexceptiontypenotpersistable) but in my case I need to do serialization not storing, maybe I'm wrong?

How do I serialize an object containing Throwable? If you can please point me to documentation or an example explaining how to do this.
Many Thanks!

Comment: Why does `ObjectToSerialize ` contain a `Throwable` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing an object containing a field of type Throwable using Java serialization with Serializable interface is doable. MicroStream [claims](https://microstream.one/products/serializer/) to "Serialize any object" but MicroStream doesn't yet support serialization of Throwable and derived types, this is an important information that should be noted.
Answered Here: https://github.com/microstream-one/microstream/issues/613